# Trying to Start Apache 2 in my VM at private cloud within Intranet

Tags: apache2, dns, letsencrypt

We have a private cloud setup which is not exposed to Internet.
While starting Apache2 we are getting the below error:

```
Failed authorization procedure. x.y.z.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for x.y.z.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain
```

IMPORTANT NOTES:

- The following errors were reported by the server:

  ```
  Domain: x.y.z.com
  Type:   None
  Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for
  ```

  x.y.z.com - check that a DNS record exists for this   domain

Comment: Where is your DNS server? When you find it .. add a dns record for this domain as the message tells you :)

Comment: Our DNS server is within intranet . I have already added in /etc/resolve.conf .We also established x.y.z.com as the the ip of this server .Kindly advice the steps

Comment: HTTP-01 offers a clue that this is about TLS certificates and ACME/Certbot. Apache doesn't require any *authorization* through DNS, nor does it really care if DNS is correctly configured. Can you add more information about your configuration? If so I can elaborate in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Failed authorization procedure. x.y.z.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for x.y.z.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain
> ```

No, you are not getting this error message when you are starting Apache. You're getting this error message when you're running certbot or another acme client, using [HTTP-01 challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#http-01-challenge).

This will ***of course*** fail, if the domain is only defined in the internal DNS infrastructure. If you want a public certificate from e.g. Let's encrypt, you ***need*** to own the domain, and the domain has to be configured in the global DNS server, so that it can be resolved by Let's Encrypts servers.

For internal sites, you probably don't want to use HTTP-01 challenge, but rather the DNS-01 challenge, which doesn't require that the domain resolves in the global DNS system, but it has to be registered in the global DNS system.